# cqlsh and nodetool command not found

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed cassandra 3.11.4 as per the below link http://cassandra.apache.org/download/ and when I'm trying to run cqlsh and nodetool command its showing command not found.
when run sudo service cassandra status,cassandra is running.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to verify that the service is healthy and operational

- verify that the process is running:

  ps -efa | grep cassandra

  The expected outcome is a valid java process being executed
- verify the log file as defined in `$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/logback.xml`

  tail -n 100 cassandra/system.log

  The expected outcome is to not find errors
- Try to replicate the issue in a new instance of the command line

Comment: red: true
ERROR [main] 2019-09-12 11:45:28,500  CassandraDaemon.java:820 - Cannot start node if snitch's data center (Cassandra) differs from previous data center (datacenter1). Please fix the snitch configuration, decommission and rebootstrap this node or use the flag -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true.

Comment: You have changed the datacenter name. If you dont have any data then you need to delete /var/lib/cassandra/data folder

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify the services whether it is running or not in the configured port and IPs.
Also, you can check the system.log for any error. if still issue and data is not important you can delete the /data /commitlog /savedcache and restart the cassandra services again.
once started just check
 ps -ef | grep cassandra